# jQuery .each callback error

Tags: jquery

I am currently messing with the `.each()` function in jQuery and I am trying to count all `div`'s with the the `id` of item and add them to a string.

The problem is, I get a callback error from my jQuery source, which I load from jquery.com's website.

```
var items = "";
$('div.item').each(function(){ 
    items += $('this').data('id');
});
```

The error, as seen on firebug;

```
callback is undefined
if ( callback.call( object[ i ], i, object[ i++ ] ) === false ) {
```

Comment: works ok for me: http://jsfiddle.net/jvnVA/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect it's not the each, it's the .data. You probably want

```
items += $(this).data('id');
```

i.e. using `this` as a variable not a quoted string.

Comment: no, i do want to get the items data value.
<div class="item" data-id="1"></div>
but if it works alike i might just use that instead

Comment: Right, I mean you're getting the error in the .data call because `$('this')` isn't being constructed as a DOM element by your browser - it's being constructed as a textnode, and the attempt to call `data` on the textnode is failing. Your mistake is quoting `this`.

Comment: ouch... how embarrassing.. you are right i messed up with the qouting for 'this' ... thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the .data() method you are using:

```
var items = "";

$('div.item').each(function(){ 
    items += $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`$(this)` instead of `$('this')`?

Check the `.data()` too. Try `.attr()` :)

Answer (score 1):

Try below but I'm not sure what you want to get from it.

```
var items = 0;
$('div.item').each( function() { 
     items += parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

To count id's with id name that starts with xyz- can be counted by below script

```
$('div[id^=xyz-]').length
```